# How to elevate privileges for child process

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to make an installer that has the admin password embedded into it, so that I can let a simple user install a package.

I know that this is not good security practice and all, but that's what I am forced (by my employers) to do.

Now, I have written all the code and I am testing it in a Win7 virtual machine.

It works running it as an admin, but not when running it as simple user (which is what I want).

This is my code:

```
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
    STARTUPINFOW sInfo = { 0 };
    sInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);
    sInfo.lpReserved = NULL;
    sInfo.lpReserved2 = NULL;
    sInfo.cbReserved2 = 0;
    sInfo.dwX = 0;
    sInfo.dwY = 0;
    sInfo.lpDesktop = NULL;
    sInfo.lpTitle = NULL;
    sInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    sInfo.dwFillAttribute = 0;
    sInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

    CString cmdLine(_T("elevPrivInstaller.exe /q /norestart"));
    BOOL ret = ::CreateProcessWithLogonW(_T("IEUser"), NULL, _T("Passw0rd!"), 0, NULL, (LPWSTR)(LPCTSTR)cmdLine, 0, NULL, NULL, &sInfo, &pInfo);
```

`CreateProcessWithLogonW()` returns zero (which is failure).

`GetLastError()` returns: `Access is denied.`

Does anyone have any idea why?

As far as I see, the credentials are correct.

Comment: You cannot do this without disabling UAC. A lower privilege process cannot run an elevated privilege process without someone providing administrative credentials via the UAC dialog at the time they're needed.

Comment: @KenWhite Oh... I was afraid of that. Is there any workaround to that? Because I do have the admin credentials. Does this only work with a human intervention?

Comment: use `ShellExecute` and mark your installer need administartor's privilege.

Comment: @Jichao But, then, who will enter the password? The low level user that runs the installer should not see the password.

Comment: @Jichao: That still requires someone to provide credentials in the UAC dialog.

Comment: @user2173353: None of which I'm aware. I find it better to stop trying to get around UAC and learn to work with it properly instead.

Comment: @KenWhite OK. Thanks. I was just hoping to get it working. I initially had the impression that it was possible, since it is possible to do in from the UI... :( But, now that I tested it, it doesn't seem to work from the UI either. WTF? :o

Comment: @KenWhite: Yes I misunderstood the question. futher reference http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2010/02/01/why-can-t-i-elevate-my-application-to-run-as-administrator-while-using-createprocesswithlogonw.aspx shows it is designed to forbid elevate appliation to run as administrator.

Comment: Thanks people. :) Not even the "Run As..." in Windows when you use `RightClick + Shift` works! You have to select `Run as Administrator`! But I have tested it with UAC off and it works fine.

Comment: Please avoid making comments like your last one. That second sentence is entirely inappropriate here. This is a professional site, and racist or sexist comments are totally unacceptable. See the [help], specifically the section on expected behavior, if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: `(LPWSTR)(LPCTSTR)cmdLine` is lightyears away from working, and probably twice as much from working fine. If you need a modifiable buffer, call `GetBuffer` and `ReleaseBuffer` (see [CStrings and const char Pointers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a994dfk.aspx#_core_cstrings_and_const_char_pointers)).

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, I have read the docs for `CreateProcessWithLogonW` and had this in mind, but this is a single copy of `CString` that does not get destroyed nor altered during the call to `CreateProcessWithLogonW`. Can you pin-point what can go wrong in this case?

Comment: [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431.aspx): *"lpCommandLine: [...] The function can modify the contents of this string."*

Comment: @IInspectable yes, I have seen this, but you *can* modify the buffer like so: `CString str(_T("Test"));    auto ptr = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)str;    ptr[0] = _T('F');`. Since I am not using this string anywhere else as a copy and since I don't do anything with CString to make it release this buffer, I don't see how I might get into trouble with this in practice. In theory I know you are right.

Comment: Of course you *can* compile constructs, that result in undefined behavior. It's just fairly hard to see, why you would *want* to. Particularly in a case, where a safe alternative exists, that requires a single additional call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this shouldn't actually be too hard, provided that UAC is configured with the default settings.

I believe that the reason CreateProcessWithLogonW() is failing is that the target executable requires elevation.  If you instead run an executable that is *not* configured to require elevation, it should work.

At that point, you are running in the context of a limited token belonging to an administrative user.  If you *then* attempt to launch an elevated process, e.g., using ShellExecute(), you will still get a UAC dialog - but it will be a yes/no dialog; the user will not need to enter the password.

Comment: Hm... I have not tried this, but I have my doubts whether or not the non-admin user will not be asked for a password. He is not the admin himself, so, in my logic, Windows should not ask him simply with Yes/No without first asking him to login as admin. But I might be wrong. Have you tried this and it worked?

Comment: @user2173353: I tested this by logging in as a non-admin user, using `runas` to open a command line window in the context of an administrative account and then running `diskpart` from that command line window.  The elevation dialog appeared but did not ask for a password.  (Windows 7 SP1 x64.)

Answer (score 0):

After the help of many people and some tests I did, here is the outcome:

Elevating privileges for a child process only works with UAC disabled. :(

Here is the info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2010/02/01/why-can-t-i-elevate-my-application-to-run-as-administrator-while-using-createprocesswithlogonw.aspx

The best you can do is show the UI for the user to enter the admin password.

Comment: The correct solution is to install a system service that launches the child process (with elevated privileges) on demand.

Comment: @HarryJohnston But the system service must be installed with admin rights, correct? The thing is that I have to deploy to MANY machines that I don't have the service running already and I don't have direct physical access to install it. Only low lever users have direct access and that creates some issues... And I guess that UAC won't let me install the service using a script for elevation either. I have found some hack solutions to bypass the UAC, but that is my last resort.

Comment: That's an ... unfortunate ... situation.  Have you investigated whether you can install software over the network?  (That's off-topic here, but you could try Server Fault.)  It depends on the existing configuration, of course, if the machines aren't in a domain and don't have any firewall exceptions configured then there probably isn't much you can do.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about remote-installation too, but the machines are not in a domain and some of them might not be on a network at all. So, I don't see this working either. But thanks! :)